# Firebase Authentication redirects wrongly to localhost

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used Angular to develop a web application. I added Firebase since I was using Firebase Auth to sign users up for my web app. Everything looks good and working really well on my Angular web app. My working codes looks like below:

```
onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, async (user) => {
  let credentials = await getRedirectResult(this.auth)
    .then(async (result) => {
      this.authUser = this.auth.currentUser
    })
  })
})

AuthLogin(provider: any) {
  return this.afAuth
    .signInWithRedirect(provider)
}
```

My second task is to convert this web app into a hybrid app using Capacitor. Building and running the mobile version work great, even when logging in using Facebook/Google redirects me to their login page, except that when it should redirects back to my app, it goes to `locahost` instead of  `https://myapp.com/__/auth/handler`.

[image]

For reference, here is my `firebaseConfig`

```
firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAmrqr92L07xVm0Om4ki_xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "myapp.com",
    projectId: "com-myapp-app",
    storageBucket: "com-myapp-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "69599xxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:69599xxxxxxxxxx:web:70747a0ca0xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Anybody got an idea how I could fix this problem?